# Favorite Questions and Answers from first quarter 2018

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

The post has now been compiled and is located at [Highlights from 2018 – 1st Quarter](https://thesffblog.com/2018/04/highlights-from-2018-1st-quarter/)

### Original

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from January 1st 2018 through March 31 2018 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers, but it also doesn't matter if you want to self promote your own stuff.**).

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/01/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/01/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/01/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter. Also the most controversial question of the quarter. Also a sum of all the bounties that were awarded.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

[image]

Comment: Holy crap, that time already is it?!?!

Comment: @Möoz Holy crap, returned Yoda has?!?!?!

Comment: @Möoz Don't get too excited. A lot can happen in two weeks.

Comment: [Search query for finding your highest-voted questions and answers for Q1 2018](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3ame%20created%3a2018-01..2018-03).

Answer (score 7):

From both a question and answer stand point I really enjoyed:

[Where did Rocket's repair tool come from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179570/where-did-rockets-repair-tool-come-from)

The questions hits on something that many people might have a assumed was common in that part of the universe. Something so important, but yet somehow just operating in background.

The answer goes right to the source, getting a WOG tweet (which has been done quite a few times on this site but is never-the-less impressive). It's always nice to see our humble community have an impact on the greater world of the stories we love.

Answer (score 6):

I don't want to toot my own horn too loudly but I really enjoyed researching this answer of mine:

[What are the lyrics to The Children from Game of Thrones S04E10?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179255/58193)

It ended up being a lot more research than I had planned and I eventually got pointed to the language creator for an answer. I put in a lot of work and ended up finding the answer to the question a few years after it was asked. This answer would fall under "Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes."